# jquery onchange not working on two method i've tried

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know what am I doing wrong on my jQuery `onchange`. Here is my code :

```
dateselect = $("#dateselect").val();
$("#dateselect").on('change', 'select', function () {
    dateselect = $(this).val();

});
```

I've also tried:

```
dateselect = $("#dateselect").val();
$("#dateselect").on('change', 'select', function () {
    dateselect = $('option:selected').next().attr('value');
});
```

You can check my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Reginald/sex4wrwg/

Comment: your understanding of `on` using target selector is incorrect. The target needs to be a descendent of selector on the left...won't work if it is the same element

Comment: but i am not getting the last value i selected somewhere outside the function even if the variable that i have used it declared global

Comment: no reason it should. There is nothing to fire that alert again...it won;t fire just because later you change what was in the alert. The order of code has nothing to do with anything either, that's only the order it is being loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just call [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in your `change` handler?

```
dateselect = $(this).val();
```

---

```
$(function() {
    dateselect = $('#dateselect').val();
    $('#dateselect').on('change', function() {              
        dateselect = $(this).val();  
        alert(dateselect);
    });
    alert(dateselect);
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rk8bkz61/)

Comment: Why when I put alert(dateselect) after the onchange varible i don't get any value

Comment: `alert(dateselect)` should be within the `change` function block. You wish to alert on every selection event, correct?

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed because that alert only runs once on page load

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed see edited answer. Now you'll alert on page load and on every `change`. This is what you're wanting, correct?

Comment: so does it means i cannot get the last value i selected outside the on change function even if  the variable that i use to assign the selected value is a global variable

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed you can totally get that value, wherever you wish. But if you want to alert on that UI interaction, a call to `alert()` should be made somewhere in that event handler. In this case, `change` works just fine

Comment: @salniro i updated ur jfiddle please check http://jsfiddle.net/Reginald/rk8bkz61/1/

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed you're still missing the additional `alert()`. See the [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rk8bkz61/) I already posted in the answer. Why take it out? This is what you need

Comment: @salniro so meaning without inner alert ,there is no way i can get the last selected value

Comment: cool thanx i understand now meaning u cannot use the last onchange value after the onchange function